# React generic component: 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Omit

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a generic component. I want to add a prop "a: string" to the properties of type T (generic).

When I extract the props using `{ a, ...props }`, props cannot be cast to T

```
const Test = <T,>({ a, ...props }: { a: string } & T) => {
  const b: T = props;
  
  return <div></div>
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-wind-dzpqsx?file=/src/App.tsx

Why is that?

Comment: Apart from `{a: string}`, `T` may have `a` in itself. For example: `{a: string} & {a: '123'}`, thus you get this error. Ideally, you could constrain that `T` has no `a` in it, but unfortunately, currently, this is not possible in typescript. What you can do is type `b` as `Omit<T, 'a'>`. Does this work for you? If yes I'll write an answer; otherwise what am I missing?